# Erro IE8 no DataTables

Tags: jquery-datatables

O `script` abaixo:

```
function _fnGetObjectDataFn( mSource )
    {
        if ( $.isPlainObject( mSource ) )
        {
            /* Build an object of get functions, and wrap them in a single call */
            var o = {};
            $.each( mSource, function (key, val) {
                if ( val ) {
                    o[key] = _fnGetObjectDataFn( val );
                }
            } );
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> 1.10.4 jquery na linha 1171 if ( $.isPlainObject( mSource ) )

Como resolvê-lo?

Comment: Adicione mais algumas informações sobre o que você está tentando fazer, qual é o erro e a versão do jquery, por exemplo. Sua pergunta está uma bagunça.

Comment: Exclarecendo quando o programa faz leitura do datatable.1.10.4 esta dando erro na linha $.isPlainObject( mSource ), isto só acontece no IE8.                                                         "Erro em tempo de execução do Microsoft JScript: O objeto não dá suporte para a propriedade ou método". Este é o erro que o IE envia.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado mas descobri que o erro é incompatibilidade de versão do jquery datatable.

Comment: Jorge, você pode responder sua própria pergunta e marcar como aceita. Dessa forma você ajuda alguém com o mesmo problema no futuro.